# ExtJS - Elegant Date Time Picker

Tags: extjs

I've found what I'm looking for but it's a jQuery example, it looks super clean and intuitive.  Is there a way to do this with xtype 'datefield'?  Is there a way to extend this field type to include a clock icon beside the date icon and have it behave the same way as in this example?

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/T3zge/

```
ko.kendo.bindingFactory.createBinding({
    name: "kendoDateTimePicker",
    defaultOption: "value",
    events: {
        change: "value",
        open:
        {
            writeTo: "isOpen",
            value: true
        },
        close: {
            writeTo: "isOpen",
            value: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        enabled: "enable",
        max: "max",
        min: "min",
        value: "value",
        isOpen: ["open", "close"]
    }
});

var viewModel = {
   myDate: ko.observable(new Date())
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I'm still very much a newbie at this so perhaps somebody can lend some advice or point me in the right direction how I can figure this out.   Thanks in advance!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extjs does have a separate Time Picker, but not a date/time picker combined. You would likely need to create a plugin, but if you are fairly new to this you may find it a little overwhelming.

You could search the forums for custom extensions/plugins people have created, I just came across [this one](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137242) for ExtJs 4.

Comment: Thanks.  For the time being I'll just use the simple timepicker.

Answer (score 7):

I have created a DateTime plugin for ExtJS 4 and 5 few months ago.
Give it a try, its a little different than what you showed but works as intended:

https://github.com/gportela85/DateTimeField

Hope it helps

Comment: Nice one, probably Sencha needs to incorporate something like this.

Comment: Adding components to the framework is a little harder because it need to be Accessibility/ARIA compliant. Now that I added support to change hours/minutes by hitting CMD+up/down and CMD+shift+up/down ... I might get a shot.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes minValue is not taking the time but only the date, do you have a solution for that?